# How can I know the voltage input range of the CS5344 ADC?

Tags: adc, cirrus

I see that this ADC has a built in voltage reference, therefore I wont have to bias my audio signal as it goes into the ADC input. The thing that confuses me is however the full-scale input voltage listed in the [datasheet](http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS5343-44_F5.pdf):

[image]

So say my supply voltage (VA) is 3.3V, does this mean that the maximum unclipped input amplitude is equal to (3.3*0.56/2) = 0.924V? This just seems low to me.

Comment: Looks like it! Here's a better datasheet link, btw. http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS5343-44_F5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is an audio digitizer. Since the standard Line In voltage is about 1 volt p/p, there is no obvious reason to require a greater input range.

And on what basis do you judge your calculated range to be low? Why, exactly, does it "just seems low to me"?

Comment: When I have used ADCs in the past, the max input voltage swing was a lot closer to the positive rail. This one is only 0.56*Vdd.